# how to populate a column by seeing another column in source whether it has a particular value then set it to a single value

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have one doubt, I have a table in that for particular distinct sk column I have two different indicators (Y,N) so for a particular sk if I have one "Y" then set every value to Y if the values all the values are N then set to N.
Sources:

[image]

Result which I needed:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Hive or MySQL?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: sorry i am using hive

Answer (score 0):

Just use `max()` as a window function:

```
select t.*, max(indicator) over (partition by number_sk) as column_3
from t;
```